# Is there a way to test a SQL Statement to see if is executable in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

I am not asking to test the SQL Statement by parsing it.

I mean something similiar to execute the SQL Statement with ADO.NET, so it will actually run in SQL Server to see if the fields name correct, table names correct, stynxs correct, data type corrects etc.

The previous developer done this by executes the SQL Statement with ADO.NET and check if is throw execption.  But the data return is a large data set, which is wasting the resources. So is there anyway I can ask SQL Server to perform a statement check for me in C#?

Comment: I assume it's a SELECT statement you want to check. If so, couldn't you run the query with SELECT TOP 1 instead of SELECT, so it only returns a single row?

Comment: @Moonshield the Select statement is user defined, I cannot ensure he entered correctly.  And if I have to do TOP 1, I will need to use regexp to check and modify the entered SQL statement to have TOP 1.

Comment: @Moonshield and just additional, I think could be better if you SELECT TOP 0 instead of TOP 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try SET PARSEONLY ON.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178629.aspx

Comment: Wouldn't you possibly be better off with `SET NOEXEC ON` instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188394.aspx

Comment: userx is right, NOEXEC is the right choice if you want to validate table names and columns names.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with PARSEONLY is, that it only checks the syntax structure. It does not resolve table and column names. So

```
SET PARSEONLY ON
GO
SELECT nocolumn FROM no.notable;
GO
SET PARSEONLY OFF
```

runs without error.

There is no clean way to achieve what you are looking for but you can try the ROWCOUNT setting:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1;

BEGIN TRAN
SELECT * FROM sys.objects;-- Your statement
ROLLBACK

SET ROWCOUNT 0;
```

The ROWCOUNT setting stops execution after reaching n rows. The explicit transaction makes sure that no changes get applied to that database. You could control the transaction from you C# code as well.

Th reason this is not ideal is that there are operations that require SQL Server to do all the work before even returning a single row. An example is the ORDER BY clause.